# Remove from ArrayList not working

Tags: java, arraylist

```
for(JCheckBox currentCheckBox : imagesToBeImportedCheckBox){ 
    if(currentCheckBox.isSelected()){
                    System.out.println("The text Box selected for removing are"+currentCheckBox.getText());
                }

             }
            for(JCheckBox currentCheckBox : imagesToBeImportedCheckBox){

                if(currentCheckBox.isSelected()){
                    System.out.println("I am entering in the loop where this image has to be removed "+currentCheckBox.getText());
                    imagesToBeImported.remove(currentCheckBox.getText());

                }

             }
            for(ResourceListObject currentImage : imagesToBeImported){

                System.out.println("After removing the images left are "+currentImage.getName());

             }
```

and here's the output

The text Box selected for removing are aix71b

The text Box selected for removing are Migration-image

I am entering in the loop where this image has to be removed aix71b

I am entering in the loop where this image has to be removed Migration-image

After removing the images left are aix71b

After removing the images left are Migration-image

Comment: I don't understand your code. I don't see why you have two "for loops" on the same ArrayList, or why you have 2 checks for "isSelected()".

Comment: It's just for explaining the problem I am facing. In the real code I am not using two for loops.

Comment: When you ask a question post the `real code`. Posting fake code is a waste of our time!

Comment: I have a big for loop after that, which is working, this is the onlyy part that's not working as expected , so I just posted this.
I would try posting full code from next time.

Comment: Instead of using an ArrayList you can use `Map<String, ResourceListObject>`. Then you remove the ResourceListObject based on the String identifier for the resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your code, most likely, this is the problem.

```
imagesToBeImported.remove(currentCheckBox.getText());
```

This tries to remove a `String`(*getText()* prompted me to say String here) named `aix71b` from the Collection `imagesToBeImported` but the Collection `imagesToBeImported` contains elements of type `ResourceListObject`.

That is why nothing is getting removed from your Collection as `String` and `ResourceListObject` are not of the same type.

**Edit:-** (You can delete from the list using the below 2 ways)

You can traverse the `imagesToBeImported`(using an *iterator*) for each element of `imagesToBeImportedCheckBox` and remove the elements from `imagesToBeImported` whenever `resourceListObjectElement.getName()` equals `currentCheckBox.getText()`.

Or else, you could override the `equals` method in your `ResourceListObject` based on the `name` field in it, so that you can do something like this to remove it from your `imagesToBeImported`.

```
imagesToBeImported.remove(new ResourceListObject(currentCheckBox.getText()));
// You need to add another constructor in your ResourceListObject class which takes in only the name field as the parameter.
```

Comment: +1, was just about to make the same comment, that is a `String` and a `ResourceListObject` will not be equal, since they are not the same type of Object.

Comment: Yes, I checked on it and looks like you are right, but then what's the correct way to remove that element from ArrayList ??

Comment: And do try to take in the suggestion given by @camickr to use a `Map` instead of a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `currentCheckBox.getText()` and `currentImage.getName()` are not exactly the same objects - `equals` method is not true for them, even if the values are the same.

Comment: Ok they are different I got that.
The problem is in this line
imagesToBeImported.remove(currentCheckBox.getText());
I have to somehow get a Image object in this . But how do I do that??

Comment: @prateek I think you need to iterate over `imagesToBeImported` and check if the current element in the iteration match the one you need to delete. If it is - remove the item and stop iteration. This operation has high time cost, but I can't see a better solution as your objects(the one you are removing and the one you got by iterating) have completly different nature.

Comment: @prateek or you may want to override `equals` method for `ResourceListObject` class so as if it gets a parameter of type `currentCheckBox.getText()` returns(the parameter type of method should be `Object` anyway, but you can check the actual type using `instanceof`) - so as the proper compare procedure is done

Comment: I used iterator to do that and that's working fine .
But maybe the thing that you are saying in your second comment can be checked by == where it checks that the things being refer to the same object or not. 
Did you mean that ??

Comment: No, `==` means left and right objects are the same single object, thus it is not what you need. I mean you need to override `equals` method and then use it instead of `==`. But as I can see you've already got a n answer.